# How to make a TabBar/TabBarView with a carousel-like behaviour in flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to make a page on which there is a TabBar - and a TabBarView which doesn't fill the whole width of the screen; so that the sides of other tabs are visible on the sides of the screen.

This is the expected result.

[image: A TabBar/View which is smaller than the screen width, and the side edges of other tabs are visible on both sides of screen]

I can't just use a padding to the TabBarView, because then the side edges will be missing.

Is there a simple solution to this that doesn't involve re-writing animations and stuff for tabbarview? Could the tabs be put into a carousel-like widget and somehow mixed with the tabbar, while retaining animations and stuff?

Comment: I just had a revelation :D If I use a Card Carousel, maybe I can replace the "slider indicator"  part of it with a tabbar?

Comment: can you add you code snippet ?